# BTRFS delete missing drive, ignoring I/O errors

Tags: linux, hard-drive, btrfs

I have a BTRFS file system, distributed on 3 drives (no raid). One of my drives died yesterday.
I can still mount the file system using

```
sudo mount $path -o degraded,ro
```

About 120k files (out of 1.1m) throw read errors, the rest is still there. I have backups, but how do I remove the missing disk from the array, without destroying all of the data?

I tried

```
sudo btrfs device delete missing $path
```

, but that outputs `ERROR: error removing the device 'missing' - Read-only file system`, but I can't mount it read/write because of the missing drive...

The obvious solution would be to copy all working data to a new file system, but I don't currently have another 4TB drive, so it would be great if I could simply have only the corrupted files deleted, and then restored from backup.

Comment: I didn't find a solution to this. Instead I copied all the data to a different disk and reformatted.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem. I added a new disk into a multi-device array that was DATA:single, METADATA:raid1, SYSTEM:raid1. The new disk failed about 2 minutes later, leaving me with this:

```
tassadar@sunfyre:~$ sudo btrfs fi usage /mnt/store
Overall:
    Device size:                   7.28TiB
    Device allocated:              7.14TiB
    Device unallocated:          140.98GiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                          7.14TiB
    Free (estimated):            141.99GiB      (min: 71.50GiB)
    Data ratio:                       1.00
    Metadata ratio:                   2.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 96.00KiB)

Data,single: Size:7.06TiB, Used:7.05TiB
   /dev/sdc1       3.53TiB
   /dev/sdd1       3.53TiB
   missing         2.00GiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:43.00GiB, Used:41.81GiB
   /dev/sdc1      43.00GiB
   /dev/sdd1      43.00GiB

System,RAID1: Size:32.00MiB, Used:880.00KiB
   /dev/sdc1      32.00MiB
   /dev/sdd1      32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sdc1      70.99GiB
   /dev/sdd1      69.99GiB
   missing         3.71TiB
```

It was only mountable with ro,degraded, which is useless when I need to remove the missing device. I couldn't find any way to fix this and the data on those disks wasn't very important, so I started hacking around in the kernel.

### Workaround

**All of below is obviously very unsafe and blindly copypasting everything might not be the best idea.**

These are the changes I made to vanilla 4.7.4 kernel tree, mostly the ancient craft of "commenting out stuff I don't really understand" ([with syntax highlighting](https://gist.github.com/Tasssadar/d63a3bb02c8734cc450a0cccc1d31990)):

```
diff --git a/fs/btrfs/disk-io.c b/fs/btrfs/disk-io.c
index 864cf3b..bd10a1d 100644
--- a/fs/btrfs/disk-io.c
+++ b/fs/btrfs/disk-io.c
@@ -3588,6 +3588,8 @@ int btrfs_calc_num_tolerated_disk_barrier_failures(
        int num_tolerated_disk_barrier_failures =
                (int)fs_info->fs_devices->num_devices;

+       return num_tolerated_disk_barrier_failures;
+
        for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(types); i++) {
                struct btrfs_space_info *tmp;

diff --git a/fs/btrfs/volumes.c b/fs/btrfs/volumes.c
index 589f128..cbcb7b2 100644
--- a/fs/btrfs/volumes.c
+++ b/fs/btrfs/volumes.c
@@ -2817,7 +2817,8 @@ int btrfs_remove_chunk(struct btrfs_trans_handle *trans,
                }

                if (map->stripes[i].dev) {
-                       ret = btrfs_update_device(trans, map->stripes[i].dev);
+//                     ret = btrfs_update_device(trans, map->stripes[i].dev);
+                       ret = 0;
                        if (ret) {
                                mutex_unlock(&fs_devices->device_list_mutex);
                                btrfs_abort_transaction(trans, root, ret);
@@ -2878,13 +2879,15 @@ static int btrfs_relocate_chunk(struct btrfs_root *root, u64 chunk_offset)
         */
        ASSERT(mutex_is_locked(&root->fs_info->delete_unused_bgs_mutex));

-       ret = btrfs_can_relocate(extent_root, chunk_offset);
+//     ret = btrfs_can_relocate(extent_root, chunk_offset);
+       ret = 0;
        if (ret)
                return -ENOSPC;

        /* step one, relocate all the extents inside this chunk */
        btrfs_scrub_pause(root);
-       ret = btrfs_relocate_block_group(extent_root, chunk_offset);
+//     ret = btrfs_relocate_block_group(extent_root, chunk_offset);
+       ret = 0;
        btrfs_scrub_continue(root);
        if (ret)
                return ret;
```

Basically, it does the whole "move extents to another device" part without actually moving the extents -> it just deletes the old ones on the missing drive. It also allows me to mount the fs read-write. **Using this "patch" with (other) healthy btrfs systems is unsafe.**

Device delete "works" now:

```
tassadar@sunfyre:~$ sudo mount -o degraded /dev/sdd1 /mnt/store

tassadar@sunfyre:~$ sudo btrfs device delete missing /mnt/store
ERROR: error removing device 'missing': No such file or directory

tassadar@sunfyre:~$ sudo btrfs fi usage /mnt/store
Overall:
    Device size:                   7.28TiB
    Device allocated:              7.14TiB
    Device unallocated:          140.98GiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                          7.14TiB
    Free (estimated):            141.99GiB      (min: 71.50GiB)
    Data ratio:                       1.00
    Metadata ratio:                   2.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 96.00KiB)

Data,single: Size:7.06TiB, Used:7.05TiB
   /dev/sdc1       3.53TiB
   /dev/sdd1       3.53TiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:43.00GiB, Used:41.81GiB
   /dev/sdc1      43.00GiB
   /dev/sdd1      43.00GiB

System,RAID1: Size:32.00MiB, Used:880.00KiB
   /dev/sdc1      32.00MiB
   /dev/sdd1      32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sdc1      70.99GiB
   /dev/sdd1      69.99GiB
   missing           0.00B

tassadar@sunfyre:~$ sudo umount /mnt/store

tassadar@sunfyre:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/store

tassadar@sunfyre:~$ sudo btrfs fi usage /mnt/store
Overall:
    Device size:                   7.28TiB
    Device allocated:              7.14TiB
    Device unallocated:          140.98GiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                          7.14TiB
    Free (estimated):            141.99GiB      (min: 71.50GiB)
    Data ratio:                       1.00
    Metadata ratio:                   2.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)

Data,single: Size:7.06TiB, Used:7.05TiB
   /dev/sdc1       3.53TiB
   /dev/sdd1       3.53TiB

Metadata,RAID1: Size:43.00GiB, Used:41.81GiB
   /dev/sdc1      43.00GiB
   /dev/sdd1      43.00GiB

System,RAID1: Size:32.00MiB, Used:880.00KiB
   /dev/sdc1      32.00MiB
   /dev/sdd1      32.00MiB

Unallocated:
   /dev/sdc1      70.99GiB
   /dev/sdd1      69.99GiB
```

Make sure to revert back to original kernel without the workaround as soon as possible.

### Result

My fs seems to be okay now. I might have lost some small amount of data that was on the failed disk, but that's expected when I ran it in "single" mode. I'm currently running btrfs scrub to see if something is horribly broken or not, will edit this post once it finishes.

**EDIT:** The scrub has finished without any problems, but **the fs is still corrupted** - when I started deleting some files from it, the kernel found some files that were on the missing drive and threw an error. So, I patched the kernel once more (this time on top of clean 4.7.4, without the previous changes):

```
diff --git a/fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c b/fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c
index 82b912a..f10b3b6 100644
--- a/fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c
+++ b/fs/btrfs/extent-tree.c
@@ -6853,8 +6853,10 @@ static int __btrfs_free_extent(struct btrfs_trans_handle *trans,

                ret = update_block_group(trans, root, bytenr, num_bytes, 0);
                if (ret) {
-                       btrfs_abort_transaction(trans, extent_root, ret);
-                       goto out;
+                       btrfs_err(info, "update_block group has failed (%d)", ret);
+                       ret = 0;
+                       //btrfs_abort_transaction(trans, extent_root, ret);
+                       //goto out;
                }
        }
        btrfs_release_path(path);
```

So yeah, definitely not a good solution, since the FS is quite obviously not okay. But since it is now usable, I didn't really lose anything and this wasn't a high-priority storage, I'm quite content.

Comment: Nice. Looks like this could have saved me the work of completely recreating my filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

sudo mount -o degraded,ro /dev/sdd1 /media/btrfs

sudo btrfs de del missing /media/btrfs
ERROR: error removing device 'missing': Read-only file system

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1148693)

Answer (score -2):

The degraded filesystem has to be mounted readwrite before starting with `btrfs device delete missing`. Mounting with `-o degraded` should work.

Comment: It did not allow me to mount it read write, because it was degraded.